# lambda-parameter to constexpr trick, then get array with linkage

Tags: c++, arrays, lambda, constexpr, linkage

I've found a use-case where it is handy to provide a lambda to a function, and have that function invoke the lambda to get a constexpr result (my real use-case involves passing a lambda to another lambda, where the first lambda returns a value obtained from a visitor pattern... but that's not relevant to my core question).

I'm trying to get an array "with linkage" that I can then use as a template parameter for other functions.  I'm seeing a very odd error where I get "invalid initialization of reference of type..." unless I either:

1. Make function `arrWithLinkage1` a template function with a throw-away template parameter,

or

2. Provide an explicit return type for function `arrWithLinkage1` such as `const array<size_t, 3>&` instead of `const auto&`

I've found a workaround, using function `arrWithLinkage2`, but I'm concerned that I might be entering the realm of undefined behavior.  Does anybody know?

Live example: https://onlinegdb.com/By9nDmsyw

EDIT: Thanks to Ted (below comment), it looks like the core issue is:
`use of 'auto' in parameter declaration only available with '-fconcepts-ts'`
So this makes me feel more comfortable with my solution using `template<typename Lam>` below, unless anyone has a reason to think otherwise...?

```
// Test that array has linkage

template<auto& arr>
void test() {}

// Get array with linkage

template<size_t... vals>
constexpr auto valsToArr = array<size_t, sizeof...(vals)>{ vals... };

// Lambda to array with linkage

template<size_t... Idx>
constexpr auto& arrWithLinkage(auto lam, index_sequence<Idx...>) {
    return valsToArr<lam()[Idx]...>;
}

template<size_t=0> // Only works with this...
constexpr auto& arrWithLinkage1(auto lam) {
    constexpr size_t N = lam().size();
    return arrWithLinkage(lam, make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

template<typename Lam> // A little less gross-looking, but still concerned that this is UDB
constexpr auto& arrWithLinkage2(Lam lam) {
    constexpr size_t N = lam().size();
    return arrWithLinkage(lam, make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

int main()
{
    auto lam = [](){ return array{1, 2, 3}; };
    
    constexpr const array<size_t, 3>& res = arrWithLinkage1(lam);
    test<res>();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd turn warnings into errors and/or turn on pedantic mode and fix any issues you get with that first: https://godbolt.org/z/ox1eE5

Comment: @TedLyngmo It works if you build with `-std=c++20`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, but it was set to C++17.

Comment: Thanks @TedLyngmo, `use of 'auto' in parameter declaration only available with '-fconcepts-ts'` !!  Not knowing much about C++20 or `concepts`, I never would have guessed that one!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

(Would mark Ted's comment as the "solution" if he posted as an answer, thanks Ted!)

1. Ted led me to the realization that the problem was indeed my use of `auto` in a parameter.  Using `template<typename Lam>` is indeed an acceptable solution.  From my googling of the above error and seeing other people do similar things, I think the solution is "defined behavior".
2. I came up with a much better overall approach.  Just make the lambda return a *reference* to a `constexpr` array with linkage from the start (using a template variable that accepts a param pack of values via a template parameter).

Live example: https://onlinegdb.com/Sy-qx3skw

```
// Test that array has linkage

template<auto& arr>
void test() {
    for(auto& val : arr)
        cout << val << ", ";
    cout << endl;
}

// Get array with linkage

template<size_t... vals>
constexpr auto valsToArr = array<size_t, sizeof...(vals)>{ vals... };

int main()
{
    // Just make the lambda return a reference to a constexpr array to begin with
    // Avoid the need to convert it to a param pack, then an array template variable
    // in order to obtain an array with linkage, that can be passed to test<>()
    
    auto lam = []() -> auto& { return valsToArr<1, 2, 3>; };
    constexpr auto& res = lam();
    test<res>();
    
    return 0;
}
```